# Understanding the generality of the NER problem

Tags: nlp, named-entity-recognition, text-classification

Named-entity recognition (NER) is a well-known problem in the NLP literature.

It typically addresses the problem to locate and classify named entities in text, e.g. `Organizations` and `Products`.

[image]

I'm trying to solve a similar problem but, in my view, a bit more general. Given an input text, I want to be able to comprehensively annotate the whole text; not only specific entities like `Actors` and `Organizations` but also higher-level concepts like `Conditions of Applicability` and `Temporal Conditions`, e.g.:

[image]

The added difficulty is that we have nested "entities", e.g. (from above):

```
<denotic> must, <temporal> within the specified period </temporal>, notify ... </deontic>
```

Can this still be formulated as a NER problem? If so, what would be the best type of model to solve this task assuming a dataset of ~ 50 K examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem described is not a more general version of Named Entity Recognition, it is a different problem called [parsing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing). Parsing consists in extracting the syntactic structure of a text, usually in the goal to better capture its semantics. There are various approaches:

- [Shallow parsing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shallow_parsing) only identifies the constituents of the sentences (based on your example this could be sufficient in your case)
- [Statistical parsing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_parsing) and in particular [Dependency parsing](https://nlpprogress.com/english/dependency_parsing.html) represent the full structure of the sentence, including the links between its constituents.

There are various libraries and datasets for parsing: one of the most famous is probably the [Stanford parser](https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/lex-parser.shtml), but there are many others often included in NLP toolkits such as [OpenNLP](https://opennlp.apache.org/). The [Universal Dependencies](https://universaldependencies.org/) project is a vast multilingual collection of annotated text which can be used to train parsers.

[Semantic Role Labeling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_role_labeling) (SRL) is a closely related task which consists in identifying the semantic relations between a predicate (verb) and its related constituents (e.g. subject, object).